# Remove specific strings from a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, string-formatting

I have a dictionary which is in this format

```
Open = {'22.0x7.5x8.0 12.0': ['4.60x4.30x4.30 13.00, 4.60x4.30x4.30 1.00, 
                              4.60x4.30x4.30 2.00, 6.60x6.00x5.16 5.00'], 
         '18.0x7.0x7.0 7.0': ['4.60x4.30x4.30 1.00, 8.75x6.60x5.60 4.00'],
           '22.0x7.5x8.0 9.0': ['6.60x6.00x5.16 5.00, 6.60x6.00x5.16 9.00, 
                                6.60x6.00x5.16 5.00']}
```

I want to remove the dimensions part(1x2x3) from keys as well as values and convert the remaining part in integer. How can I do that ?

such that my output is like this

```
new = {12:[13,1,2,5],
          7:[1,4]...}
```

Comment: Any attempts from yourself? Have you tried `str.split()`?

Comment: What code have you tried for it?

Comment: Write a regex that matches the pattern and use it to `replace` the string with the empty string. Then cast to int for the keys, and for values split the string by `", "` and cast each list element to int.

Comment: `print({k.split()[1]: [j.split()[1] for i in v for j in i.split(",")] for k,v in Open.items()})` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `str.split` should be enough.

```
Open = {'22.0x7.5x8.0 12.0': ['4.60x4.30x4.30 13.00, 4.60x4.30x4.30 1.00',
                              '4.60x4.30x4.30 2.00, 6.60x6.00x5.16 5.00'],
         '18.0x7.0x7.0 7.0': ['4.60x4.30x4.30 1.00, 8.75x6.60x5.60 4.00'],
           '22.0x7.5x8.0 9.0': ['6.60x6.00x5.16 5.00, 6.60x6.00x5.16 9.00',
                                '6.60x6.00x5.16 5.00']}

res = {}
for key,value in Open.items():

    #Split on space and convert to int for key
    k = int(float(key.split()[1]))
    li = []
    for v in value:
        #First split on comma
        for i in v.split(','):
            #Then split on space
            num = int(float(i.split()[1]))
            #Append the number to a list
            li.append(num)
    #Assign the list to the key
    res[k] = li

print(res)
```

The output will be

```
{12: [13, 1, 2, 5], 7: [1, 4], 9: [5, 9, 5]}
```

Comment: Sure thing! Can we also replace float with int? I tried that, it's saying that I cannot use int with float items

Comment: Done Sir! @RahulSharma just do `int(float('12.0'))` in future to get `12` etc

Answer (score 1):

Using `str.split`

**Ex:**

```
Open = {'18.0x7.0x7.0 7.0': ['4.60x4.30x4.30 1.00, 8.75x6.60x5.60 4.00'], '22.0x7.5x8.0 12.0': ['4.60x4.30x4.30 13.00, 4.60x4.30x4.30 1.00, 4.60x4.30x4.30 2.00, 6.60x6.00x5.16 5.00'], '22.0x7.5x8.0 9.0': ['6.60x6.00x5.16 5.00, 6.60x6.00x5.16 9.00,6.60x6.00x5.16 5.00']}

print({float(k.split()[1]): [float(j.split()[1]) for i in v for j in i.split(",")] for k,v in Open.items()})
#Or
#print({int(float(k.split()[1])): [int(float(j.split()[1])) for i in v for j in i.split(",")] for k,v in Open.items()})
```

**Output:**

```
{9.0: [5.0, 9.0, 5.0], 12.0: [13.0, 1.0, 2.0, 5.0], 7.0: [1.0, 4.0]}
```

Comment: While the answer is very good, but it's not very readable IMO due to the depth of for-loops in the dict comprehension